# How to connect php 5.3.8.1 to MS SQL Server 2000?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I need to connect a php script (running on php 5.3.8.1) to MS SQL Server 2000. I've been told that **mssql_** commands are not supported anymore and **sqlsrv_** ones are used now. Any help ???

Answer (score 1):

See the [manual entry](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php). There's a bunch of good examples in the comments. In general, you'll do something like this:

```
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"dbName","UID"=>"userName","PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Comment: Connection could not be established.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires either the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client (SP1 or later) or the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client ODBC Driver to communicate with SQL Server. Neither of those ODBC Drivers are currently installed. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712...................

Comment: So the code is correct, but you need the appropriate driver installed. Follow the link as indicated, install the driver, and run it again.

Comment: So did you go to the URL and install the latest drivers?

Comment: the problem that is i dont know which driver to install to connect php 5.3.8.1 (on windows 7) to MS SQL Server 2000 (on windows server 2003) !

Comment: The page describes what your options are, based on your environment. I'd start with either php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll or php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll